# How to pass boolean values from Blade to Vue Component Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

I'm trying to implement `IF` condition with true/false or 1/0 in Vue Component. I go through some earlier asked questions but not able to get it. Please help me out.

`IF` condition not gives `true` output even if `dd` gives `true`.

Controller (I tried with two ways so that either I may got success with true/false or 1/0, In both methods on page I'm able to get 1/0 or true/false with dd($isExamAssigned)):

```
    dd($isExamAssigned); // here I'm able to get 1 or 0
```

blade.php:

```
    <quiz-component
   
   :isExamAssigned = "{{$isExamAssigned}}"
   >
</quiz-component>
```

code part from Component.vue:

```
props:['isExamAssigned'],

data(){

    return{

            isExamAssigned :this.isExamAssigned,

        }
```

and here is the IF condition:

```
<div v-if="isExamAssigned === '1'">

                        <!-- Code here for IF -->

                    </div>


                    <div v-else>

                        <!-- Code here for ELSE -->

                    </div>
```

I tried different ways to get the values, like:

```
<div v-if="isExamAssigned === 1">

<div v-if="isExamAssigned === true">

<div v-if="isExamAssigned">
```

but **Im not able to implement condition**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting it to string value of `'1'` in the vue component. Later you are strict comparing it to an integer, boolean and boolean again. The most correct approach would be to set it to a real boolean like so. The second approach you had would work.

```
$isExamAssigned = DB::table('quiz_user')->where('user_id', $authUser)->where('quiz_id', $quizId)->exists();
```

Now PHP type juggles weird, if you print out `$isExamAssigned` it will print out 1. You can try with `{{true}}` and see the result yourself. To avoid this, do the following check in your blade file when setting the component.

```
:isExamAssigned = "{{$isExamAssigned ? 'true' : 'false'}}"
```

This will make the following if statements work.

```
<div v-if="isExamAssigned === true">

<div v-if="isExamAssigned">
```

Comment: Sir now I changed the lines in blade, controller and component, but its not working yet.

Comment: dd($isExamAssigned) gives the exact output that I want, i.e. if quiz assigned to user then it give true otherwise false, don't know where the problem is. Please help.

Comment: You cant have props and data together with the same name, you don't have to set it in data. So remove your data field isExamAssigned

Comment: And you have inconsistencies with naming of your props, it should be kebab-case parsed to the component, but in your component be camelcase. So isExamAssigned should be :is-exam-assigned="true" when you give it to the component

Answer (score 16):

Try passing the prop like this in your blade.php file

```
:isExamAssigned="{{ json_encode($isExamAssigned) }}"
```

This will send the prop in Boolean format.

Comment: In case someone else hits this, pay attention to the short hand for `v-bind` (the colon in `:attr-name`) in @Himanshu Sharma's answer.  If you leave that out Vue won't know to interpret `"false"` as an expression instead of a string.  ie. you get `"false"` instead of `false` in your vue props.

Thanks @Himanshu Sharma!  This was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 9):

Himanshu's answer is correct, it can also be written like:

`:isExamAssigned='@json($isExamAssigned)'`

Answer (score 1):

Mrhn's answers is true.

You can make Laravel do the casting for you by setting the cast on the model.

```
// On a model, e.g. App\Models\Exam.php

$casts = ['is_exam_assigned' => 'boolean'];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting